# Explain the syntax of reserved.get(t.value,'ID') in lex.py

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, tokenize, lex, lexer

Code taken from ply.lex documentation: http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn6

```
reserved = {
   'if' : 'IF',
   'then' : 'THEN',
   'else' : 'ELSE',
   'while' : 'WHILE',
   ...
}

tokens = ['LPAREN','RPAREN',...,'ID'] + list(reserved.values())

def t_ID(t):
    r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
    t.type = reserved.get(t.value,'ID')    # Check for reserved words
    return t
```

For the `reserved` words, we need to change the token `type`. Doing `reserved.get()` by passing to it the `t.value` is understandable. Now it should return the entities in the second column in the `reserved specification`.

But why are we passing to it `ID`? What does it mean and what purpose does it solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter specifies the value to return should the key not exist in the dictionary.  So in this case, if the value of `t.value` does not exist as a key in the `reserved` dictionary, the string `'ID'` will be returned instead.

In other words, `a.get(b, c)` when `a` is a dict is roughly equivalent to `a[b] if b in a else c` (except it is presumably more efficient, as it would only look up the key once in the success case).

See the [Python documentation for `dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).